# Can a custom formula return an array that populates some cells with #ERROR but not others?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible for a custom formula to output an array where some output cells are populated with a `#ERROR` error message, while others contain normal values?

My use case is that I'm automatically ingesting a large array of raw inputs into one sheet. The custom formula cleans and pre-processes each cell of raw input into a more usable form in another sheet. A few inputs may be invalid and I want to flag these for the user to fix at source, but they shouldn't break the workflow of the valid inputs. A `#ERROR` response is a familiar UX for this problem and I don't want to reinvent that wheel.

#### Example:

Say I have a function `timesTwo(cell_or_range)`, which can take either a single cell or a range, and emits something of the same shape ([this convention](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization)).

```js
function timesTwo(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)){
    return obj.map(timesTwo);
  }
  if (obj == 5) {
    throw "Three, sir!";
  }
  return obj * 2;
}
```

Say I have the numbers {1, 2, 5, 3} in the range `A1:A4`. 5 is an invalid input.

**Desired behaviour:** I'd like `=timesTwo(A1:A4)` or `=ARRAYFORMULA(timesTwo(A1:A4))` to generate `2, 4, #ERROR, 6`.

**Actual behaviour:** If the custom formula throws an exception, all outputs fail (obviously, because the function never returns its output array). `=timesTwo(A1:A4)` results in single cell showing `#ERROR`.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(timesTwo(A1:A4))` does the same, but more complex formulas like `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A4)), timesTwo(A1:A4), "whatever"))` may generate `#ERROR, #ERROR, #ERROR, #ERROR`.

#### Alternatives / workarounds:

I've tried the following:

*Don't use ranges, just explicitly auto-fill the custom formula.* Much, *much* slower because it invokes the custom formula for each cell separately. Breaks if new data is ingested which extends beyond the auto-filled range.

*Output human-readable text indicating the error.* (E.g. a literal string `"#ERROR"`, as opposed to an error message.) Needs explicit handling in anything that consumes the output, so it's fragile. Needs conditional formatting to highlight for the user; doesn't have that nice cue of `#ERROR` with a details popup on mouseover.

*Filter bad outputs out completely. Show them to the user elsewhere.* Changes the shape of the data. Breaks the consistency of the custom function (it has to behave differently with arrays compared to scalar values).

#### Remarks:

Builtin functions do have the property I'm looking for. For example, `=ARRAYFORMULA(1 / (A1:A4 - 5))` gives `-0.25, -0.333, #DIV/0!, -0.5`. [Named functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534) preserve this behaviour too. But they're not a workaround because if you can use them then you didn't need a custom function in the first place.

I think this question probably reduces to, "Can a custom formula return a value, without throwing an exception, that generates a `#ERROR`?"

Comment: - [custom Function Return Values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

I understand your expected result as follows.

- Modifying `throw "Three, sir!";` to `return "#ERROR!";` is not your expected result.

  - By the way, in your showing script, `return obj.map(myFunction);` is `return obj.map(timesTwo);`?
- You want to put an error of 8 of `ERROR.TYPE` into cells. [Ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238305?hl=en)

If my understanding is correct, how about the following answer?

#### Modified script and formula:

In this answer, your showing script is modified as follows.

```js
function timesTwo(value) {
  if (value == 5) {
    throw "Three, sir!";
  }
  return value * 2;
}
```

When the values `1, 2, 5, 3` are put into cells "A1:A5", a sample formula for using this script is as follows.

```
=BYROW(A1:A4,LAMBDA(range,timesTwo(range)))
```

#### Testing:

When the above script and formula are used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- In the above script, I guess that `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A4)), timesTwo(A1:A4), "whatever"))` might be as follows.

  ```
  =BYROW(A1:A4,LAMBDA(range,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(range)), timesTwo(range), "whatever")))
  ```

Comment: I guess the problem with this would be multiple simultaneous invocations of the custom function for bigger ranges. From your idea, I think I would keep returning a array in custom function and send errors  like `return "error_custom"` and `=LET(output, timesTwo(A1:A4), arrayformula(IF(output="error_custom" , na(), output )))`

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. I understand your comment. When I saw the question, I thought that OP wanted to create a custom error message with 8 of `ERROR.TYPE`. So, I thought that the above approach might be close to the goal. If 7 of `ERROR.TYPE` can be used, I think that your idea can be used.

Comment: @Tanaike: Thank you very much for your answer! Your assumptions are all correct and I've edited my question a little to meet them. BYROW/BYCOL isn't a fully general solution (slow for large ranges, only works for one-dimensional ranges), but it works for my use case.

Comment: @Dave Hughes Thank you for replying. If my proposed method was useful for your situation, I'm glad.

Answer (score 2):

[`ERROR.TYPE` `6`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238305), `#NUM!` can be returned by returning `NaN` and is more appropriate for this  specific function. Though I didn't have luck with other error types.

```
function timesTwo(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)){
    return obj.map(timesTwo);
  }
  if (obj == 5) {
    return Number.NaN;
    return Error( "Three, sir!"); // returns empty 
  }
  return obj * 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could return a value with ERROR.TYPE = 8...